# Data-Binding not working in knockout.js using datatable pagination

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

I am binding the list into table using Knockout.js. In this for sorting, pagination I am using the datatable. On 1st page data-binding is working correctly. But if I move to 2nd page it's not working. It will be great if somebody will help. I am new to Knockout.js.Here is my code

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered thumbnail-table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="8%"> Pip Code</th>
            <th width="30%">Full Description </th>
            <th width="20%">Product Description </th>
            <th width="5%">Size</th>
            <th width="5%">Quantity</th>
            <th width="10%"> Manufacturer </th>
            <th width="10%">Brand Name</th>
            <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAll" /></th>
            <th width="10%">Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach : {data: items,
                                            options: {
                                                paging: true,

                                            }}">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectRow">
            <td data-bind="text:$data.pipCode"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.fullDescription"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.productDescription"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.size"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.quantity"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.manufacturer"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:$data.brandName"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:$data.include,click: function(){return true}, clickBubble: false" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:50px" class="form-control" data-bind="value:$data.stock,click: function(){return true}, clickBubble: false" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted a while ago, but for anyone else finding this, you should check out [this article](https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2017/12/knockoutjs-jquery-datatables-avoiding-knockoutjs-performance-issues-with-large-data-sets/)
tl;dr KnockoutJS can’t bind to HTML elements hidden by DataTables Pagination